# Ruby on Rails Slim Templates with HTML Entity Escaping

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, html-entities, slim-lang

I have a RoR slim template with the following:

```
input(type="text" placeholder="I'm looking for&hellip;")
```

But sadly it outputs the HTML entity escape 'as-is' i.e. string literal. I'm using the rails gem 'slim' for template rendering the input field.

Desired output with the ellipsis character …

```
<input type="text" placeholder="I'm looking for…">
```

Actual output

```
<input type="text" placeholder="I'm looking for&hellip;">
```

I've tried adding a html_safe call to the end but to no avail e.g.

```
input(type="text" placeholder="I'm looking for&hellip;").html_safe
```

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Could you post the Original output and desired output please.

Answer (score 3):

Self solved, simple solution, obvious answer - set of parenthesis needed:

```
input(type="text" placeholder=("I'm looking for&hellip;".html_safe))
```

Comment: Just a note: the "preferred" way is to use the `raw` or possibly even the `sanitize` method. The only advantage of `raw` over `html_safe` as it currently stands is that it calls `to_s` on the object before marking it as `html_safe`, so it works on anything that can be converted to a string, not just strings. I guess there's a small chance of it doing more complicated stuff in the future.

Comment: Just another note: "set of parenthesis is actually not needed". Previously you were calling `html_safe` on `input` which was not right and now you are calling it on the string and then putting it in as value of placeholder attribute.

Answer (score 0):

According to Slim's [website](https://github.com/slim-template/slim) , Text is escaped by default. To prevent escape, prefix with double equals signs. So (un-intuitively),

```
input(type="text" placeholder=="I'm looking for&hellip;")
```

should work just as well.

For stand-alone unescapes, one could use

```
span.classname[onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'"]
  =="&times;"
```

Remember: make sure the escape character is surrounded by double quotes!

Answer (score -1):

```
<%= text_field_tag nil, nil, placeholder: "I'm looking for&hellip;".html_safe %>
```

or give more info about your input helper

Comment: That's not SLIM, that's ERB.